# Python to sort two correspondent lists by values (of one list)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There are two corresponding lists of 1-to-1 relationship.

```
names = ["David", "Peter", "Kate", "Lucy", "Kit", "Jason", "Judy"]
scores = [1,1,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.6]
```

I want to show whoever scored more than 0.5 and display in 1 line:

```
Peter (1 point), David (1 point), Kate (0.8 point), Judy (0.6 point)
```

What I tried is:

```
import operator

names = ["David", "Peter", "Kate", "Lucy", "Kit", "Jason", "Judy"]
scores = [1,1,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.6]

dictionary = dict(zip(names, scores))

dict_sorted = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print dict_sorted
```

It gives:

```
[('Peter', 1), ('David', 1), ('Kate', 0.8), ('Judy', 0.6), ('Kit', 0.4), ('Lucy', 0.2), ('Jason', 0.1)]
```

How can it further proceed to have the result wanted?  Note: sorted result from large to small is required.

2 longer lists for testing purpose:

```
names = ["Olivia","Charlotte","Khaleesi","Cora","Isla","Isabella","Aurora","Amelia","Amara","Penelope","Audrey","Rose","Imogen","Alice","Evelyn","Ava","Irma","Ophelia","Violet"]
scores = [1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.6]
```

Comment: You don't need that dictionary. Just operate on the list of tuples returned by `zip`, as shown in mentalita's answer. BTW, in Python 3, `zip` doesn't return a list, it returns an iterator, but mentalita's code will work correctly in both versions.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
names = ["David", "Peter", "Kate", "Lucy", "Kit", "Jason", "Judy", "Mark", "John", "Irene"]
scores = [1,1,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.7,0.3,1.2]

print(', '.join('{} ({} points)'.format(name, points) for name, points in sorted(zip(names, scores), key=__import__('operator').itemgetter(1), reverse=True) if points > 0.5))
```

output:

```
Irene (1.2 points), David (1 points), Peter (1 points), Kate (0.8 points), Mark (0.7 points), Judy (0.6 points)
```

Comment: when I changed the Scores to a longer list, the result produces outcome not sorted (from big to small). could you please have a look?

Comment: @MarkK Although the code in your question performs sorting, you don't actually mention in your question that you want the output to be sorted. You should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line, but it's much easier to read if you do it in stages. First select the items with a score greater than the threshold, and then sort them.

```
import operator

names = ["Olivia","Charlotte","Khaleesi","Cora","Isla","Isabella","Aurora","Amelia","Amara","Penelope","Audrey","Rose","Imogen","Alice","Evelyn","Ava","Irma","Ophelia","Violet"]
scores = [1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.6]

threshold = 0.5
lst = [(name, score) for name, score in zip(names, scores) if score > threshold]
lst.sort(reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[('Olivia', 1.0), ('Charlotte', 1.0), ('Amara', 1.0), ('Imogen', 1.0), ('Irma', 1.0), ('Khaleesi', 0.8), ('Evelyn', 0.8), ('Violet', 0.6)]
```

---

Here's the one-liner version:

```
print(sorted(((name, score) for name, score in zip(names, scores) if score > 0.5), reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Comment: Can I ask for your kind understanding? mentalita's answer came first and he also supplied an update. You're famous and well known and have many scores. Would you mind I choose mentalita's for the best answer for this question?

Comment: your help and sharing is very important. please don't get angry.

Comment: However, I should mention that it's a little more efficient to do the sorting after the items with the scores > 0.5 have been selected. ;)

Comment: @MarkK It's nice to get the points, and the accept, but I also enjoy seeing good answers written by others, and helping people to improve their answers. FWIW, I upvoted mentalita's answer before I started writing my own.

Comment: present rose to others with remaining fragrance in your hands. kisses!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `OrderedDict` form `collections` module, if you want the sorted output.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

names = ["David", "Peter", "Kate", "Lucy", "Kit", "Jason", "Judy"]
scores = [1,1,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.6]

dict_sorted = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in zip(names, scores) if v > 0.5)
print(', '.join('{} ({} points)'.format(k, v) for k, v in dict_sorted.items()))
```

prints:
`David (1 points), Peter (1 points), Kate (0.8 points), Judy (0.6 points)`

Comment: just missing ")" at the end of line "dict_sorted", and "a.items" shall be "dict_sorted .items". @Alex Pshenko, could you please advise the way that the result can be sorted from large to small? thank you.